# How to move an button up a bit in html

Tags: html, css

I having a trouble making the search button beside the search box.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<form action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="am-form-field">
    <span class="am-input-group-btn">
    <button class="am-btn am-btn-primary" type="button submit"><span class="am-icon-search"></span> </button>
    </span>
    </form>
```

I'm using AmazeUI CSS framework 
https://github.com/amazeui/amazeui/

here is the CSS:

```
 .am-form-field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: post your CSS that defines that class.

Comment: i had update the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can (depending on the browser support you want to achieve) use flexbox, just add `display: flex` to the form tag.

Otherwise you can set a width to the input.am-form-field (like 80% or whatever) and add `float: left` to it